# How to sort a dict by key of versions

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, versions

Input:

```
foo = {
    'testing-1.30.5': ['The', 'quick'],
    'testing-1.30.12': ['fox', 'jumped', 'over'],
    'testing-1.30.13': ['the'],
    'testing-1.30.4': ['lazy', 'dog'],
    'testing-1.30.1': ['brown'],
    'testing-1.30.3': ['the'],
    'testing-1.30.6': ['brown'],
    'testing-1.30.2': ['fox', 'jumped', 'over'],
    'testing-1.30.14': ['lazy', 'dog'],
    'testing-1.30.8': ['the'],
    'testing-1.30.0': ['The', 'quick'],
    'testing-1.30.10': ['The', 'quick'],
    'testing-1.30.11': ['brown'],
    'testing-1.30.7': ['fox', 'jumped', 'over'],
    'testing-1.30.9': ['lazy', 'dog']
}
```

Do some sorting

```
bar = sortfoo(foo)
```

Desired output:

```
for item in bar:
    print '{}: {}'.format(item, bar[item])



testing-1.30.0: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.1: ['brown']
testing-1.30.2: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.3: ['the']
testing-1.30.4: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.5: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.6: ['brown']
testing-1.30.7: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.8: ['the']
testing-1.30.9: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.10: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.11: ['brown']
testing-1.30.12: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.13: ['the']
testing-1.30.14: ['lazy', 'dog']
```

Ideally I would like this to be pythonic, in that I wouldn't do something crazy like splitting the key into components and building a new dictionary based off that;

What I tried:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict(sorted(foo.items()))
    print '{}: {}'.format(item, od[item])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got it! nevermind, found LooseVersion / strict versions

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
from collections import OrderedDict

orderedKeys = sorted(foo, key=LooseVersion)

odict = OrderedDict((key, foo[key]) for key in orderedKeys)

for item in odict:
     print '{}: {}'.format(item, odict[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort `foo` with an appropriate sort key. You'd have to chop off the "testing-" part, then split the rest on the periods, then turn each of those into an integer. Also, the result will be a list of keys, so look up those items in the original dictionary.

```
>>> bar = sorted(foo, key=lambda x: map(int, x.split('-')[1].split('.')))
>>> for item in bar:
...     print '{}: {}'.format(item, foo[item])
...
testing-1.30.0: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.1: ['brown']
testing-1.30.2: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.3: ['the']
testing-1.30.4: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.5: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.6: ['brown']
testing-1.30.7: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.8: ['the']
testing-1.30.9: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.10: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.11: ['brown']
testing-1.30.12: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.13: ['the']
testing-1.30.14: ['lazy', 'dog']
```

Note that for Python 3 you would have to wrap the `map()` in `list()` or `tuple()` to consume the lazy `map` object.

Answer (score 0):

In the sort function, split the key on `'.'` and cast the last item in the *splitted* list to integer:

```
for k in sorted(foo, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('.')[-1])):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, foo[k]))
```

---

Output:

```
testing-1.30.0: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.1: ['brown']
testing-1.30.2: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.3: ['the']
testing-1.30.4: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.5: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.6: ['brown']
testing-1.30.7: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.8: ['the']
testing-1.30.9: ['lazy', 'dog']
testing-1.30.10: ['The', 'quick']
testing-1.30.11: ['brown']
testing-1.30.12: ['fox', 'jumped', 'over']
testing-1.30.13: ['the']
testing-1.30.14: ['lazy', 'dog']
```